# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups' attempting a loop

Tags: python, regex

I am using a regular expression to strip data.

If I hardcode the data and match it with the regular expression, it works fine. But if I use a for each loop, passing the loop variable to `re.match()`, I get the following error:

```
     re.VERBOSE
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'**
```

My code:

```
trs = soup.findAll("tr")
for tr in trs:
    c = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', tr.text)
    y.append(str(c))
for x in y:
    #data1 = "Ambala 1.2 Onion 1200 2000 1500"
    x1 =    ([c.strip() for c in re.match(r"""
        (?P<market>[^0-9]+)
        (?P<arrivals>[^ ]+)
        (?P<variety>[^0-9]+)
        (?P<min>[0-9]+)
        \ (?P<max>[0-9]+)
        \ (?P<modal>[0-9]+)""",
        x,
        re.VERBOSE
    ).groups()])
```

If I set `data1 = "Ambala 1.2 Onion 1200 2000 1500"`, then it works fine.

Can anyone tell me how to properly iterate it in a loop to get the values and avoid the error.

Comment: Can you please specify what you're trying to do? Why do you loop each character?

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you're trying to do with the loop, but I'll answer why that error is raised.

It looks like you're trying to match a **character** with that regex.

```
y.append(str(c))
```

appends a character to `y`, and then you loop each character with

```
for x in y:
```

That regex **will never match 1 character**, because it requires at least 8 characters to match.

When `re.match()` doesn't actually match the string, the **`object has no attribute 'groups'`**, which is the error you get.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is structured such that you do not expect to find a match every time but rather only want to collect the matches. You can separate your inline loop to build x1 and check

```
 x1 = []
 for x in y:
    tmp = re.match(r""" ...""",x)
    try:
       x1 = ([c.strip() for c in tmp.groups])
    except AttributeError:
       print "no match found in x:{}".format(x)
```

or with an if statement

```
   ...
   if tmp is not None:
      x1 = ([c.strip() for c in tmp.group])
   else:
      print "no match found in x:{}".format(x)
```

If your data should find some match always then your regular expression is incorrectly formatted and you need to debug that. (I find the ipython terminal particularly useful for testing regex when I am designing them